# How to assess the transaction response time with while loop / counter and fail it if it is not successful

Tags: jmeter

I am uploading a file via API for which I do a ‘polling’ and have the following 2 steps / transactions:

1. HTTP request to upload it for which I get a temporary status response ‘uploading’
2. While loop with a counter until the response status changes to ‘success’ but not more than 10 times.
   ${__javaScript("${STATUS}" != "success" && ${counter} < 10,)}

**Question-1**: How do I measure the response time for step-2 as it varies (sometimes, file will be uploaded in 2 times and sometime in 8 times)?

**Question-2**: How to make step-2 fail when the status has not changed to success even after all 10 iterations/ attempts?

Please could someone help?

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

1. Put everything under [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller), it will measure duration of all the iterations.
2. You can go for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion), example code would be something like:

   ```
   if (vars.get('counter') == '9' && vars.get('STATUS') != 'success') {
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Status is ' + vars.get('STATUS') + ' after ' + vars.get('counter') + ' iterations')
   }
   ```

   put it as a child of the 2nd request and if after 10 iterations the status won't be `success` it will mark the sampler as failed.